# Can I use microsoft interop dll 2010 on machine having MS-Office 2003

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have used MS Interop 2010 DLL in ASP.Net project to generate word and excel docuement. But On deployment server client has office 2003.

My concern is that will MS Interop DLL 2010 will work with MS-Office 2003 or need to install MS-Office 2010?

NOTE: In development in environment I have installed MSOffice 2010 and MS Interop 2010 works well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interops must fit with the office version, becuase they are only a kind of interface to access the office functionality. So you need to install the correct MS Office Version, which should automatically install the interops.

Comment: That is a lie. There is no need to install a corresponding Office version. You can build a software even without Office installed.

Comment: In my point of view this is true. You can not run any method which uses the interops. This means you can not test you software in the development enviroment. So it's not completly true, but also not completly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install the corresponding Office version or interops. You can use latest interop libraries for old Office versions until you use the absent members. For example, a method was introduced in Office 2010 and you try to call it in Office 2003. In that case you will get an exception at runtime. So, I'd recommend checking the Office version at runtime and only then call the new members or not.

Moreover, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

As a workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. Or just use any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.